# Total and aggregate percentage in hive

Tags: sql, hive, count, hql, percentage

I have a table like

```
fruit   sold
----------------
apple   5
apple   10
apple   3
orange  2
orange  5
```

I wanna get the total and also aggregate percentage. So the output would be

```
fruit   sold
----------------
All     25
apple   52%
orange  48%
```

As of all sold apple is 13/25 and orange is 12/25.

Comment: How come total sold apple is 13 and total sold orange is 12?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's `union all` between a query that generates the total sum, and another that computes the total per fruit:

```
select 'All' as fruit, sum(sold) sold from mytable
union all
select fruit, 100.0 * sum(sold) / sum(sum(sold)) over()
from mytable
group by fruit
```

One thing to be careful about is that the datatypes of the subqueries need to be aligned. This puts everything as numbers (both the total sales, and the percentages per fruit).